# AWS StepFunction - Failed to update state machine

Tags: aws-step-functions

I had a working StepFunction state machine with 4 steps triggering 4 Lambdas.

Since one of the steps is going to be a longer running task, I decided to turn one of the Lambdas into a Fargate task.

After configuring ECS and Fargate task, I tried updating my state machine definition, but got the error: `Failed to update state machine.` without any additional messages.

My state machine definition seems to be valid, here it is, just without actual ARNs:

```
{
  "Comment": "My Workflow",
  "StartAt": "Step1",
  "States": {
    "Step1": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "copy-pasted-arn-of-lambda",
      "Next": "Step2"
    },
    "Step2": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
        "Cluster": "copy-pasted-arn-of-cluster",
        "TaskDefinition": "copy-paster-arn-of-task-definition",
        "Overrides": {
          "ContainerOverrides": [
            {
              "Name": "container-name",
              "Command.$": "$.commands"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "Next": "Step3",
      "Catch": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "Next": "Step4"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Step3": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "copy-pasted-arn-of-lambda",
      "Next": "Step4"
    },
    "Step4": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "copy-pasted-arn-of-lambda",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

This is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Any ideas? I've been banging my head on this one for a while.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As it is always with AWS, it's permissions.

I forgot to allow my StepFunction access to events, which is needed:

```
"Action": [
  "events:PutTargets",
  "events:PutRule",
  "events:DescribeRule"
],
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/ecs-iam.html

However, I'd really appreciate a more verbose error message!

Comment: Indeed, in learning AWS, the permissions part takes most of the time!

Comment: An example for IAM Pemissions in CodeBuild => [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/codebuild-iam.html](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/codebuild-iam.html)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this a hundred times!

Answer (score 0):

After 3 years from the first question, I found AWS still showing the same dumb error message.

I have a state machine start executing another statemachine. If I choose sync, sync:2 or waitForTaskToken without those events privileges, I got the same error.

So for anyone having same problems in nested step functions, just add those events privileges.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer and I still got the mysterious error. It *was* a permissions error, but try as I might, I couldn't figure out the proper IAM permissions.

I fixed the issue by letting Step Functions automatically generate a new role  [image: The Create new role option]